# How can I share a sound to whatsapp in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, audio, resources, share

I tried it like this:

```
shareBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
                shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://com.example.aaron.sharetest/sound.mp3"));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Sound shared!"));
```

But this is not working, whatsapp tells me to try it again.

I also found this way in the answers of [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686469/sharing-audio-file):

```
String sharePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
        + "/Soundboard/Ringtones/custom_ringtone.ogg";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("audio/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```

What do I have to write instead of this in my case?:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + "/Soundboard/Ringtones/custom_ringtone.ogg"
```

My sound.mp3 file is located in the raw folder

Comment: where is your audio file located?

Comment: @jagapathi in the raw folder

Answer (score 0):

You can share Raw folder files using this code

> **name** = file name

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("audio/*");
 sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(
        "android.resource://"+ this.getPackageName()+"/raw/" + name
));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

Comment: If I click on whatsapp it still says "Sharing failed, please try again"

Comment: checking it let you know when i find the sol